# How to create proxy for golang package sources

Tags: go, dns, go-modules

Let's say I have all source code for module hosted on `github.com/example/my-module`. But I want to create a proxy hosted on `example.com/my-module` to redirect all requests to `github.com/example/my-module` and use my custom domain name in `import`s:

```golang
package main

import "example.com/my-module"
```

instead of:

```golang
package main

import "github.com/example/my-module"
```

According to docs, I can host git repository on `example.com/my-module`, but it would be overhead for me.

How can I set up package source code proxy for Go on custom domain? Can I just use HTTP reverse proxy for that or it doesn't work?

Comment: No need for a proxy. Just serve appropriate meta tags as described in https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths

Comment: What Volker said. But you can also study the resuls of [this Internet search engine query](https://www.google.com/search?q=golang+vanity+import+paths).

Answer (score 1):

If you just need it for yourself, or your package's users are open to an extra step to including the package in the go.mod, you could use the "replace" function of the mod file: https://thewebivore.com/using-replace-in-go-mod-to-point-to-your-local-module/